# A pda that accepts all strings over an alphabet

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, regular-languages, pushdown-automata

If you were asked to construct a pda that recognizes all strings over the alphabet {a,b,c,d}, that is

L={w | w belongs to (a,b,c,d)*}

How would that be constructed? My idea is to have one state as the initial and final state and have all transitions loop on the same state without pushing or popping anything from the stack, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. In fact, you don't need the stack, since the language is regular (and trivial). A single state DFA is enough.

Comment: @Shaull Ya I figured, but to have it be technically as a PDA I just need more symbols to represent what is being replaced in the stack, right? which is epsilon by epsilon every time.

Comment: Yes. that's correct.

Comment: Techic ally, a PDA pops a symbol each transition (and it's transition depends on it, that is the whole point), and pushes a string on it's stack. You can certainly arrange to have the same symbol on top of the stack, your starting stack symbol, and replace it by the same each move. Accept by final state, and you are done.